# How to set the weight of an entire mesh?

Tags: animation, armature, weight-painting

I am creating a simple lever in blender for an animation. I have connected it to a single bone for rotation. When I weight paint the mesh to the bone, however, I cannot paint the entire mesh. The brush always leaves an unpainted vertex. Is there any way to set the weight of an entire object so that every vertex will be painted?

Comment: Couldn't you simply ctrl P > parent to bone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into edit mode on the mesh. Press A to select everything, then go to the object data tab to the right. It looks like an upside down pyramid. Under vertex groups, you should see a group named the same as your bone. Press assign with everything selected. That should work.